# advertise() function parameter for vector type

Tags: ros, publisher, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to publish a vector (cpp) in my publisher, and I do not want to create my own message. Is there already a built-in type for it? What I mean is to replace `"std_msgs::Float64"` part below:

```
ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("/radar", 500);
```

I already checked [the message types here](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/std_msgs/html/msg/) and I couldn't see anything for vector. I already desperately tried `std_msgs::vector<int>` and it didn't work, gave parameter error, seems like it is not the way.

Any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227383/advertise()-function-parameter-for-vector-type/) by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't want to do your own, `Float64MultiArray` is the equivalent. A vector is essentially a 1-dimensional array.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1